# How to get karma to run a init function first?

Tags: karma-runner, karma-mocha

Ive got a weird problem, Ive got a JS library I pull down from a CDN, and before I can use it I need to run an init function on it, and then run my tests. Anyone got any ideas how I can do that?

In my actual project I call the init function first, then call the rest of my code from the inits callback, but I just cant figure out how to do this for a test

Answer (score 0):

You can list CDNs in your karma config:

```
files : [
  'http://theurl.totheserver/thelibrary.js',
```

Then assuming the library has initialization function that takes a callback function as a parameter:

```
describe("My tests", function() {  

 before(function(done) {
  myLibrary.initialization(done);
 });

 describe("My test cases", function() {
```

However I would consider using Bower to manage your front end dependencies rather than relying on CDNs.